# C++ read two input files differently

Tags: c++, file-io

I have two files listed in "input.txt", I can read in the first one using:

```
while (getline(inFile, name))
{
    datFile.open(name, ifstream::in);
    ...
}
```

But when it gets to the end of processing datFile, it will go back and try to open the other file (second file listed in "input.txt", which I do not want to process the same way. How can I open the second file and process it differently than the first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are guaranteed to have two files in your input.txt file (inFile), take getline out of a while loop... call it once to get the first file, process it, then call it again and process the second file after the first one is done.

Alternatively, you could use break to exit the while loop as soon as datFile is done processing... but that isn't as sound logically.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
int idx = 0;
while (getline(inFile, name))
{
    if (idx == 0)
    {
       datFile.open(name, ifstream::in);
       ...
    } else
    {
       ...
    }
    idx++;
}
```

Comment: Note: This will process any file after the first file listed with the else logic. If you are guaranteed to have two lines as input, why not just call getline twice outside of a while loop and check to make sure the return is true before processing each one?

Comment: `How can I open the second file and process it differently than the first?`. My solution does that. As long as nothing is mentioned about the next to come files my solution is as good as any for them.

Comment: That is true, good point.  I guess I am just too worried about the 'what ifs'.

Answer (score 1):

You must have three `ifstream` objects;

```
std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
std::ifstream file1;
std::ifstream file2;

std::string fileName1, fileName2;
getline(inFile, fileName1);
getline(inFile, fileName2);

file1.open(fileName1, open as you ilke);
file2.open(fileName2, open as you like);

process both files independently.
```

Alternatively, if keeping the file open is undesirable, rewrite the last three lines as:

```
file1.open(fileName1, open as you ilke);
process file1;
file1.close();   

file2.open(fileName2, open as you like);
process file2;
file2.close();
```

In the second scenario you can use the same `ifstream` object.